# Twitter REST Api 1.1 POST friendships/create

Tags: twitter, access-token

I was trying to implement Twitter [friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create) by using REST Api 1.1 with PHP. But no matter how I tried it returns with

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message] => Bad Authentication data
                    [code] => 215
                )
        )
)
```

and my code is (using Abraham library and changed twitterauth to v1.1)

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth( $this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret, $oauth_token,     $oauth_token_secret);

$test_create = $twitteroauth->post('friendships/create',array('follow'=>true,'user_id'=>'2529416xx'));

print_r($test_create);exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert (I've got the same problem), but I think you shouldn't change the oauth version since it remains 1.0a. More information can be found here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints and here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request
The change it's only in the URL of the request, for instance:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem like yours also. And the solutions are simple : dont change the version number (remains 1.0) and change the host to $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";

that solved mine!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code
Here your_screen_name you need to pass your screen_name and instead of your_user_id you need to pass your user id

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['token'] , $_SESSION['token_secret']);

$connection->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name'=>'your_screen_name','user_id'=>'your_user_id','follow'=>'true'));
```